# В конце программы ошибка Run-Time Check Failure #2

Tags: c, массивы

Сделал вот такую штуку, которая берет массив, и вычисляет сумму кубов положительных чисел в нем. Вроде все ок, все делает хорошо, все считает. Но в конце, когда программа закончилась выдает такую ошибку: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted и указывает на последнюю скобку. Что не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int i;
    printf("Введите количество элементов \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
    int s, g, a[] = { i };
    s = 0;
    for (g = 0; g < i; g++)
    {
        printf("Введите число \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &a[g]);
    }
    for (g = 0; g < i; g++)
    {
        if (a[g] > 0)
        {
            s = s + a[g] * a[g] * a[g];
        }
    }
    if (s > 0)
    {
        printf("%d \n", s);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Все числа отрицательные или равны нулю \n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл вот этого вашего `a[] = { i }`? Чего именно вы пытались этим добиться?

Comment: @AnT, чтобы определяло, сколько элементов в массиве. Это так не работает?

Comment: Нет, никакого отношения к "чтобы определяло, сколько элементов в массиве" такой синтаксис не имеет. Размер массива в С указывается в `[]`. Например, `int a[i];`. Но это требует поддержки VLA компилятором.

Comment: @AnT, я пробовал a[ i ], но выражение должно иметь константное значение

Comment: Значит ваш компилятор не поддерживает VLA. Придется либо объявлять "большой массив, которого точно хватит" (напр. `int a[1024];`), либо выделять массив через `malloc`.

Comment: Также, что такое `#include <iostream>`??? Что это делает в вашем коде? И как вы это смогли скомпилировать?

Comment: @AnT это какая-то библиотека вроде. Я честно уже не помню. Просто из прошлых программ Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V

Comment: В языке С нет такой библиотеки и компилироваться это не может никак. Если у вас это компилируется, значит вы нас все это время обманывали, поставив тэг [C] на свой вопрос. Зачем вы поставили тэг [C], если вы пишете программу на C++?

Comment: @AnT, 1)Если это не C, то что тогда? 2)Я делаю как мне объясняли, а мне объясняли, что эта штука нужна

Comment: Я же написал: вы работаете в C++, а на вопросе зачем-то поставили тэг [C]. В С нет никакого `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @AnT, эмм... ну хорошо, буду знать тогда... правда я вроде с просто C работал О_о

Comment: Я же написал: в С нет никакого `#include <iostream>`. О каком "я вроде с просто C работал" может идти речь, если вы сами же в своем коде использовали `#include <iostream>`?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы объявляете массив

```
int s, g, a[] = { i };
```

из одного элемента, то либо не пишите за пределы `a[0]`, либо не удивляйтесь, что валите программу...

Comment: Кто тут заминусовал - если ответ неверный, вы уж поясните, почему, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Видимо Вы не указали вариант решения данной проблемы (к примеру указание варианта с malloc/calloc). Меня крайне вгоняет в ступор Ваше недоумение сложившейся ситуации с Вашим ответом.

Comment: @Beeen007 Я сторонник того, что если разжевать и положить в рот - такая пища толку не даст. Человек сам должен разобраться. Намек на проблему (по-моему, очень ясный) должен привести к самостоятельной работе. Если не получается - спросить, будем работать дальше. Сверхзадача же не решить за человека программу, а научить его, причем так, чтобы он **сам** прошел по пути - только тогда он в следующий раз будет знать, куда идти, а не где, на каком сайте просить решить за него. *"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

Comment: Да я согласен с Вашим тезисом, но все-же Мы (сообщество) сами заинтересованы в качественных ответах (Вы можете и отрицать это) но мы все сами ищем ответы на различные проблемы на данном ресурсе расположенном во всемирной паутине. Иногда это (ответа с обоснованиями) экономит Ваше (ну или Наше) время )))